# Use VBA to open .tbl file in notepad

Tags: excel, import, notepad++, notepad, vba

I'd like to use VBA to open a .tbl file in notepad (or notepad++). Basically, I have some .tbl files that I can drag and drop into notepad++ to edit, and I'd like to do that same thing through VBA. I can take care of the editing once the file is open. I just can't find anything about opening a non-txt file in notepad using VBA.

Opening in Excel destroys the formatting, so I'd like to stick with a text editor.

Thanks!

Comment: `Shell "notepad.exe ""C:\file.tbl"""`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple VBA module that invokes Notepad++:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim res As Variant
    Dim fileToOpen As String
    Dim nppPath As String

    fileToOpen = "F:\test.tbl"
    nppPath = "F:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

    res = Shell(nppPath & " " & fileToOpen, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Shell` returns a `Double`, not `Variant`, you don't need that `Double` to begin with, and there should be double quotes around the file name.

Comment: This did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have sufficient reputation to comment on Andrea's code (which works for me). I did want to point out one thing for the benefit of others. I encounter an error using Andrea's code unless I put in a space after .exe ". Other than that small observation mine adds nothing to Andrea's answer.

```
Sub OpenInNotepadPP()

Dim FullFilePath       As String

FullFilePath = "C:\FilePath\FileName.txt"

Dim MyTxtFile As Variant

'Note, a single space needs to be placed after notepat++.exe "
MyTxtFile = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe " & FullFilePath, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```